# Isn't there a necessity for categorizing questions and answers?

Tags: feature-request, downvotes, upvotes, users, downvote-reason

I am raising this topic because my answers (which I have worked on my best to answer and help the OPs) are constantly being downvoted.

A small comment telling the defect would help me understand the error that I missed while answering would help me to decide whether the answer can be improved or else just delete it.

But commenting every downvote and upvote would increase noise as well.

So there should be an algorithm in Stackoverflow to categorize the level of question and answer. The categorization should be based on the relevance of subject matter, codes tried and tested, formattings done etc. And users should be made compulsory to comment on higher level questions and answers while upvoting or downvoting. The low level questions and answers should be allowed to be upvoted or downvoted without comments.

So I repeat again **Isn't there a necessity for categorizing questions and answers?** for upvotes and downvotes.

Comment: *my answers...are constantly being downvoted* You have 999 answer posts and only 2 have a negative score.

Comment: ... I'll be honest, I hadn't seen this variation of "can we comment on downvotes" yet.

Comment: @BSMP Of the undeleted answers anyway.

Comment: @BSMP do you know how many I have deleted that were downvoted. I have left those two beacause they have upvotes too

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier but they marked it as duplicate

Comment: @Ramesh because it is a duplicate. You are asking for the same thing, ultimately. There will be no mandatory commenting on voting, in any way.

Comment: *do you know how many I have deleted that were downvoted.* No, users can't see each others deleted questions, at least not under 10K. How many do you have? And how many down votes did you get?

Answer (score -28):

Yes , i agree with you !

There is a strict need for this action , I have been downvoted 5 time for my
 one single questions for no reason , and if any reason was there ! Then no one told my why they put my question to the [on hold]
So , this needs to be improved and I agree with @Ramesh

Let's consider one of my own answers - 
[Mirrored Pattern Printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49686544/mirrored-pattern-printing/49687277#49687277)
In the answer I have given the solution very clearly what is asked , but someone down voted me ? Why ? No reason given to me ?

That's the problem !!

Let me take one more example :
[Improve display in mobile devices and improve user interface for writing answers using mobile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365667/improve-display-in-mobile-devices-and-improve-user-interface-for-writing-answers)
Above given is one of my meta posts - just a suggestion , then what's the need of down voting ?

Comment: It's literally *impossible* to close a question without giving a reason for why it merits closure.  Every single question of yours that was put on hold had a reason provided for why the question wasn't acceptable.  In your specific case, your question was closed as being too broad.

Comment: Ok , lets say on hold questions were due to some reasons , but no one told me that reason clearly and secondly , I would ask a question if I didn't understand it so that i could get some explanation but , those who sent my question for on hold stated that my question was off topic and bored ....etc.... ,

Comment: Well , then , where do you think I'll get my answers from ??¿¿

Comment: But you *were* told the reason clearly.  You just...didn't bother to read it apparently.  That you don't know where else to get your answers from doesn't make your question any more appropriate on SO.  You can either try to find some other place to get  your answer (there are lots of others) or you can try to improve your question such that it's acceptable on SO.  I'd suggest the latter (if only because those improvements would also be useful if you take your question elsewhere, as SO's guidelines are largely guiding people to good questions in general).

Comment: Oh, and that you didn't understand something, and thus felt the need to ask a question, again doesn't make it okay for your question to have problems requiring it to be closed, like it being too broad, unclear, missing information needed to answer it, being off topic, etc.  You can ask a question without any of those problems even if you don't know the answer to the question.

Comment: I have updated my above post , take a look at the two links...

Comment: There are many thousands of posts on meta of people asking for comments to be mandatory with downvotes.  If you're interested in seeing others' opinions on the topic there is more out there than  you could want to read on the topic, you only need to look for it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49686544/mirrored-pattern-printing/49687277#49687277 , why down vote me for no reason ?

Comment: @MASTER: ***You*** are not being downvoted. *Your question* is being downvoted. Downvotes are not *personal*; they're not about *you*; they're about what you've done.

Comment: Whatever they are , according to you , why are my answers downvoted ? , ok ?

Comment: Presumably, they are not good answers, maybe badly explained, badly designed or actually incorrect.  Currently, there is no mechanism for having downvotes or close votes explained beyond that given by the tool-tip message and canned close reasons, (mod, the custom close reasons, which are not common).  Very few users would want an in-depth anaysis of the votes on their question because they would be implicitly asking for extra work from voters and, given the rates usually charged by skilled and experienced developers, such a service would be very expensive.

Comment: _"Above given is one of my meta posts - just a suggestion , then what's the need of down voting ?"_ Voting is different on meta. For a feature request like that it indicates if someone agrees (upvote) or dissagrees (downvote)

Comment: Your meta question is downvoted because people disagree with it. The answer you link to here lacks a lot of details explaining why it works and what it does. It seems to be 'copy this, OP' and little else. Ideally you want to include an explanation of what it does. This way your answer has value for more than just the OP. Someone with a similar question will be able to use your explanation and apply it to their problem. Hard to do if your answer is just code, purely tailored to the OP.

Comment: I think we have made many comments , close this session now , I got 1 possible reason , but yet have 1 unanswered

Comment: Although I used to left a comment explaining why the question are bad, I no longer do that now, as they can be found in the help center or meta or on the close reason. Leaving a comment for everything I downvoted is too much of a mess.

Comment: Looking at your post history, I can only see one post being downvoted, and explaining the executable file format of 16/32/64 bit program is, as written, -- too broad.

Comment: Lol. We give you reasoning for the downvotes, which you say weren't warranted, and you go 'I don't want to hear this anymore'. You are definitely open to feedback sir.